# Why do (seemingly) unrelated DOM lookups cause transition to be respected?

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  var x = element.getBoundingClientRect().x;
  var y = element.getBoundingClientRect().y;
  element.style.left = x + 'px';
  element.style.top = y + 'px';
  element.style.position = 'fixed';
  window.scrollX; // (comment out this line to break the code!)
  element.style.left = parseFloat(element.style.left) + 30 + 'px';
}, 1000);
```

```css
#element {
  background-color: #fa4;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: static;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="element"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to take  a `static` positioned element and changed to `fixed` in the same place, then change the `left` value to move it around. The element's `style.transition` property is set to `1s`.

The following does not work in chrome/safari/firefox (the element jumps to its new position instead of smoothly transitioning):

```
let x = element.getBoundingClientRect().x;
let y = element.getBoundingClientRect().y;
element.style.left = x + 'px';
element.style.top = y + 'px';
element.style.position = 'fixed';
element.style.left = parseFloat(element.style.left) - 500 + 'px';
```

On the other hand, the following slightly different code *does* work:

```
element.style.left = element.getBoundingClientRect().x + 'px';
element.style.top = element.getBoundingClientRect().y + 'px';
element.style.position = 'fixed';
element.style.left = parseFloat(element.style.left) - 500 + 'px';
```

In fact, even this works:

```
let x = element.getBoundingClientRect().x;
element.style.left = x + 'px';
element.style.top = element.getBoundingClientRect().y + 'px';
element.style.position = 'fixed';
element.style.left = parseFloat(element.style.left) - 500 + 'px';
```

Or this (!!):

```
let x = element.getBoundingClientRect().x;
let y = element.getBoundingClientRect().y;
element.style.left = x + 'px';
element.style.top = y + 'px';
element.style.position = 'fixed';
window.scrollX;
element.style.left = parseFloat(element.style.left) - 500 + 'px';
```

I am trying to deepen my understanding of javascript. Can someone explain to me what causes the last 3 examples to work?

Obviously, I can guess this is something to do with the browser being forced to "recognize" the new `left` and `top` values before the `left` value is changed again in the last line, but I would like to know exactly why and how this is happening, and also if this phenonemon is known by some name.

Comment: Please add a minimal working version of your code by including the relevant HTML and CSS as well. Place your code in a "code snippet" so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Use the code editor by clicking the bracket icon `<>`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus OK thank you, have added a code snippet.

Comment: I hope the duplicates (and the links therein) explain everything you wanted to know